# ASP.Net Print dynamic value (Payment receipt)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

In my application i want to print payment receipt.If i enter amount and click on save it will print automatically.

The data look like

Thank you for receiving 
  **Text Box value( from payment page)** amount . 
In the print i don't need any thing like URL except data .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for the most part, you will be unable to control this.

You can do a few tricks such as a separate `media=print` CSS style sheet which will allow you to fully customise the page, however, you will still be at the mercy of whatever web browser your visitor is using - most of which print headers and footers.

The best thing I can suggest if this is very important is to look at integrating a PDF component in to your application - It won't be easy, but, it should work well.

You can then have the confirmation page as normal and a dynamically built PDF document that will be loaded from the same information. You can then fully customise it to your exact needs.

I am currently trying to do something very similar myself - currently [looking at this example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) with PDF Sharp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a java applet, this might work:

http://code.google.com/p/jzebra